# SQL Server Configuration Manager - Can't change "Start Mode" to Manual

Tags: sql-server

I'm running Windows 10 with SQL Server 2012.
As I am not using SQL Server frequently, I am trying to change the "Start Mode" of all its processes to "Manual" (thru SQL Server Configuration Manager).

When I try to open the pulldown menu, the configuration manager does not give me the capability to modify the "Start Mode".

I am running SQL Server Configuration with "Run as administrator"
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t5z6.png)
["SQL Server Services" panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uZBg.png)
[services.msc has pulldown menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T45Sn.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I don't have a SQL 2012 instance handy, but on both 2008 and 2014, I can select Automatic, Manual, or Disabled under the `Start Mode` field on the Service tab in SQL Server Configuration Manager for all services (engine, browser, agent, full-text filter).

Comment: Thanks Doug. I edited my question accordingly

Comment: That's a very unusual dropdown for Start Mode. I was expecting Manual and Disabled to be grayed out. I've never seen it with just the leftmost couple of pixels. Although it isn't recommended to modify SQL service settings in the Services control panel, it might shed some light. If you look at the service in the Services control panel, are the Manual and Disabled options available?

Comment: There are no pulldown menus in the "SQL Server Services" panel.
See picture in the original question

Comment: How about in the Services control panel portion of the Windows Control Panel? (Type `services.msc` at a Run prompt, or find Services in the Administrative Tools section of Control Panel (maybe inside the System and Security category).) Find the SQL service, right-click, Properties, General tab, look in the Startup Type dropdown.

Comment: Hello Doug. Your recommendation works.
See picture I added in original question.
Thanks again

Comment: The reasons to use SQL Server Configuration Manager instead of `Services.msc` are mostly related to password or account changes. (https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/03/05/use-sql-server-configuration-manager-services-applet-services-msc-interview-question-week-112/_ ) In this case, changing the startup mode via `Services.msc` should be safe. So go ahead and use `Services.msc` to set it to Manual. (As a side-effect, that might jostle SQL Server Configuration Manager to display the options properly.)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and I found the answer on [another Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880373/13723591).

In short, what worked for me is to explicitly launch the 32-bit version of the SQL Server Configuration Manager (SSCM). Since you were on Windows 10, you probably launched SSCM by running

```
C:\Windows\System32\SQLServerManager11.msc
```

Instead, you need to run

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc
```

Note the `SysWOW64` in the path.